# Bash: Difference running a command directly VS from a variable

Tags: bash

In Bash, when I run `echo 'hello'`, this will output `hello`, whereas if I put the same command in a variable (i.e., `HELLO="echo 'hello'"`) and run from the variable instead (i.e., `$HELLO`) the output is `'hello'` (note single quotes).

Instead if I run `eval $HELLO` the output is the same as running `echo 'hello'` (i.e., the output is `hello`, without single quotes).

I am trying to understand why running a command from a variable (i.e., `$HELLO`) behaves differently in Bash.

Thank you.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: It's because variables get expanded partway through the process of parsing a command; because of this, the value of the variable is only *partly* parsed (it misses the earlier phases of parsing... like quote processing).